# favorites button in the tableviewcells

Tags: iphone, xcode, uibutton, sender

I implemented the following method in my tableviewcontroller for showing favorites with empty star and filled star:

```
-(IBAction) tapped:(UIButton *)sender
{
    if([sender isSelected])
    {
        //...
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"fav-empty.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [sender setSelected:NO];
    }
    else 
    {
        //... 
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"fav-filled.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [sender setSelected:YES];
        NSLog(@"%@",sender);
    }

}
```

and I tried to use in this part:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        UILabel *recept_neve=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 40)];
        [recept_neve setTag:1];
        UIButton *kedvenc_btn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [kedvenc_btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"fav-empty.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];//default appereance on the startup
        kedvenc_btn.frame=CGRectMake(200, 20, 50, 50);
        [kedvenc_btn setTag:2];
        [kedvenc_btn addTarget:self action:@selector(tapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [[cell contentView] addSubview:recept_neve];
        [[cell contentView] addSubview:kedvenc_btn];

        //[(UILabel*) [[cell contentView] viewWithTag:1] setText:[receptek objectAtIndex:indexPath.section*blokk+1]];
        //[(UIButton *) [cell contentView] viewWithTag:2];



    }
    // Configure the cell...
    cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    [(UILabel*) [[cell contentView] viewWithTag:1] setText:[receptek objectAtIndex:indexPath.section*blokk+1]];

    return cell;

}
```

My problem is that every fifth button in the cells are working as would be the same.
If I tap on the button(empty star) in the first cell, the result will be the following: the first button becoming filled-star, so far so good(the expected behaviour), but in the same time the sixth star becoming filled too. Or if I tap on the second one, the seventh star getting filled and vica versa...

I logged the buttons where I tapping , and I realised, that the memory adresses are equals in the case of buttons above mentioned.
Sorry about my english, and thanks a lot for every help in advance!

Comment: Try to put (UITableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; and see what happens please. I am not sure. For some reason the if statement seems not to be true every fifth time. Can it be that there are about 5 cells visible at any one time?

Comment: What do you mean? Where should put "(UITableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];" exactly?

Comment: yes, i just seeing 5 cells one time, beacouse of the grouped cells

Comment: ...instead of just  [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; in your code above

Comment: unfortunately dont work, the memory adresses and the result stayed the same:

Comment: if i tap two different button(the first and the sixth):
2011-09-28 01:17:50.418 TabNav[1410:207] <UIButton: 0x602e7e0; frame = (200 20; 50 50); opaque = NO; tag = 2; layer = <CALayer: 0x602d100>>
2011-09-28 01:18:09.353 TabNav[1410:207] <UIButton: 0x602e7e0; frame = (200 20; 50 50); opaque = NO; tag = 2; layer = <CALayer: 0x602d100>>

Comment: close your if statement after the cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease]; and not where it is now }
    // Configure the cell. that should do it...

Answer (score 1):

the problem was that you reused the buttons all the time.

I show you a sample working code to structure a customized UITableViewCell correctly...
Let's do it step by step.

Create a new class called MyObjTableViewCellForSelection and provide these methods. Adapt it to your needs!

```
@class MyObj;

@interface MyObjTableViewCellForSelection : UITableViewCell
{
    MyObj *myObj;
    UIImageView *imageView;
    UILabel *titleLabel;

}

@property (nonatomic,strong) MyObj *myObj;
@property (nonatomic,strong) UIImageView *imageView;
@property (nonatomic,strong) UILabel *titleLabel;

@end
```

Then the implementation:

```
    @implementation MyObjTableViewCellForSelection
    @synthesize myObj;
    @synthesize imageView;
    @synthesize titleLabel;


    - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
    {
        self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
        if (self) {

            imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectZero];
            imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
            [self.contentView addSubview: imageView];

            titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectZero];
            [titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0]];
            [titleLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
            [titleLabel setHighlightedTextColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
            [titleLabel setLineBreakMode: UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
            titleLabel.numberOfLines = 2;

            [self.contentView addSubview: titleLabel];

        }
        return self;
    }

    -(void) layoutSubviews {
        [super layoutSubviews];
        [imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(8.0, 10.0, 20.0, 20.0)];
        [titleLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(40.0, 1.0, 250.0, 40.0)]; //two lines

    }

    - (void)setMyObj:(MyObj *)myObjX {
        if (myObjX != myObj) {
            [myObj release];
            [myObjX retain];
            //myObj = myObjX; //only with ARC on
        }

       titleLabel.text = whatever you need accessing myObj
    }

    - (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
    {
      //  selection has to be adapted to your structure
        [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
        switch (myObj.selectedFlag) {
            case MYOBJ_STATUS_UNSELECTED:
                imageView.image =  [UIImage imageNamed:@"EmptyBullet.png"];
                 break;
            case MYOBJ_STATUS_SELECTED:
                imageView.image =  [UIImage imageNamed:@"GreyBullet.png"];
                break;


            default:
                break;
        }

@end
```

now in your view class you can finally do:

```
- (MyObj *)myObjForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     MyObj* tmpObj = get the corresponding object
     return tmpObj;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyObjTableViewCellForSelection *cell = (MyObjTableViewCellForSelection *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellID"];
    if (cell ==  Nil) {
        cell = [[ECUTableViewCellForSelection alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cellID"];
    }
    cell.myObj = [self myObjForIndexPath:indexPath]; //the assignment calls setMyObj of CLASS ECUTableViewCellForSelection that you just declared

    return cell;
}
```

So finally that's the clean way of doing it...

Comment: Do you mean change the line

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

to:

UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

?? we have already discussed this, and doesnt solve the problem.

Comment: right, i got it.
i tried, and the result is the following:
i tap the star it is ok( the expected behaviour ), then i check what about the others, so i scrolling the cells, and i scroll back to the tapped star, and the tapped star is empty again,im confused.
btw the labels are disappeared from the cells too.

Comment: I posted a complete working sample solution since it was easier than adapting your code - I was under the wrong assumption that your code would create a clean new table view cell...